Create a PostgreSQL foreign key reference with default value of NULL
Consider the following table definition:
CREATE TABLE containers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id SERIAL REFERENCES containers(id)
);

When I INSERT INTO containers(name) VALUES('test_name'), I'm getting the following:
SELECT * FROM containers;
 id |   name    | parent_id
----+-----------+-----------
  1 | test_name |         1
(1 row)

It looks like the default values for parent_id is the id value of the same row. Ideally, it would be NULL. I tried to achieve this with the following:
CREATE TABLE containers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id SERIAL REFERENCES containers(id) DEFAULT NULL
);

But got the following error:

ERROR:  multiple default values specified for column "parent_id" of table "containers"

Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?

Use INT as datatype for parent_id, not a serial

Read Serial and it will become obvious what the issue is.

To ensure that the parent_id column defaults to NULL instead of the same row's id value, you need to adjust your table definition.
The issue arises because the SERIAL type automatically creates a sequence and sets a default value, which conflicts with specifying DEFAULT NULL

This is the correct answer. Don't use serial here.

The typical use case here would be inserting a new child record with a priori knowledge of what the child's parent is.  So assuming your initial record had already been inserted, we might expect an insert along the lines of the following:
INSERT INTO containers (name, parent_id) VALUES('sweet child of parent', 1);

In your case, if the intention be to insert the root parent (being defined as the one record itself having no parent), then you should explicitly mention NULL as the parent_id:
INSERT INTO containers (name, parent_id) VALUES('root', NULL);


I understand, it's just the the default value doesn't make sense. At least, is it possible to explicitly require a value for parent_id (remove the default value)?

...to the contrary, it makes perfect sense, as the auto generated id value is 1, and you didn't override with some other explicit parent_id.

It doesn't solve the real problem with the data type. serial is not the correct data type in here, you need an integer.
